# WPF combo box text converter when IsEnabled changes

Tags: wpf, combobox, converters, isenabled

I've to change the `Text` property of a combo box when `IsEnabled` sets to false and it can manually selects field from the items source when `IsEnabled` is true from the same control, is this possible?

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbIntervals"
                        Grid.Row="5"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Width="150"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkBox,
                                              Path=IsChecked}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static res:Parameters.Instance},
                                                Path=Intervals}"
                        Text="{Binding [Intervals],                                         Mode=TwoWay,
                                         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
              <ComboBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">                       
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="1"/>                            
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.Style>
              </ComboBox>
```

Comment: you want to set some Text to your ComboBox when Disabled??

Comment: @user1805169, change to something fixed when disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check in ViewModel

```
if(!IsChecked)
{
TextProperty="1"; //Propery to bind to ComboBox Text
}
```

Comment: I added this one to control but when i disable one check box which IsChecked property binded to target ComboBox is going to disable but Text value is not changing. And i set Value="1" where ComboBox ItemsSource=1,2,3,4....

Comment: check my post i updated with XAML, so when combobox disabled i need to show Text as 1.

Comment: You need to define these two properties in comboBox  IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"..See my Answer.

Comment: Yes i added but no change in Text

Comment: U need to disable the combobox ithrough code because your text is bind to a property.so what you need to do now is if your combobox is disable set text something through code

Comment: By calling event or through converter?

Comment: No this combobox and some other controls were binded based on selected data row from data table.

Comment: I am saying you just need to check in your viewmodel when your Combobox is disabled and then set the text property to desired TEXT.